# API gets stuck after not so many calls

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests

I'm working with an API and the documentation doesn't state the exact limits on the requests I make, this causes my app to suddenly stop working because of long waiting periods and eventually timeouts.

Is there a way to find out what the API limits are and build a workaround? such as "if API limits are 5 requests per minute then wait a minute before sending the 6th request" or so ...

The API I'm talking about here is the TD Ameritrade API, documentation:
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/home

I'm coding with Python.

Thanks for anybody who helps.

Edit: Problem was solved, the API can handle 120 calls per minute.

Comment: can u share the code so that we can a feel of what you are doing?

Comment: "Is there a way to find out what the API limits are": Yes. Ask the owners of the API. Usually these are well documented.

Comment: Piggybacking on this question, what is the cost for a commercial account if you actually need to go past these limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit every minute. So, it's says at the bottom of this page : https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/authentication-faq

> All non-order based requests by personal use non-commercial applications are throttled to 120 per minute. Exceeding this throttle limit will provide a response with a 429 error code to inform you that the throttle limit has been exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

API calls, especially private accounts are restricted to be able to preserve processing power to people who pay for the service, like companies do.

---

For about 2 minutes of searching in the [documentation](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/getting-started), I managed to find this line:

> All private, non-commercial use apps are currently limited to 120 requests per minute on all APIs except for Accounts & Trading

**Please, read the docs carefully before posting here!**

---

By the way, you can calculate that you have `120 calls / 60 seconds`, which means `1 call / 0.5 second`.
You can simply `sleep` for that amount of time, or delay the call of a new thread, if your app is designed that way.

Since you did not provided any code, I will show you a basic example using `sleep`.

```
import time

while True:       #main loop
    apicall()     #apicall here
    time.sleep(1) #sleep 1 second after each call
```

But I strongly suggest adding your code to the question, so people can provide you better solutions.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have looked into the API's docs and couldn't find that line, thanks very much.